# Matching an optional '#' does not seem to be working properly

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to get full words or hashtags from a string, it seems as though I'm applying the 'optional character' ? flag wrong in regex.

Here is my code:

```
print re.findall(r'(#)?\w*', text)

print re.findall(r'[#]?\w*', text)
```

Thus 'this is a sentence talking about this, #this, #that, #etc'

Should return matches for 'this' and '#this'

Yet it seems to be returning a list with empty strings as well as other random things.

What is wrong with the regex?

EDIT:

I'm attempting to get whole spam words, and I seem to have jumbled myself...

```
s = 'spamword'
print re.findall(r'(#)?'+s, text)
```

I need to match the whole word, and not word parts...

Comment: `this is a sentence talking about this, #this, #that, #etc`, why you want to match only 'this' and '#this' in your string?

Comment: Why shouldn't it match `'sentence'` or `'talking'` if the `'#'` is optional?

Comment: What I mean is that #tag or tag should return as a match. yet I'm getting empty matches, or just '#'

Comment: how a regex knows this? if you make `#` as optional, it should matches `sentence`, .... etc.

Comment: `re.findall(r'#?\w+', text)` will give you: `['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', 'talking', 'about', 'this', '#this', '#that', '#etc']` what else did you expect?

Comment: stupid me, in all of my re-arranging code I lost track that I was using a variable (which represents a spam word...) ... my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use word boundary in your regex:

```
s = 'spamword'
re.findall(r'#?' + s + r'\b', text)
```

Comment: Thanks - I would not have solved that one on my own. Getting proper results now - [u'#hot', u'#hot', u'hot', u'#hot', u'#hot']

Answer (score 0):

The above answers really explains why,Here is one piece of code that should work.

```
>>>re.findall(r'#?\w+\b')
```